# How to add next previous buttons on the popup?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I tried to add the next button on the popup box. Now it is run popups in a specific order. Also, when the final popup open, the button disable automatically. but there is an issue. when I delete some modal, the code is not working. I want to run popups in that order and when I delete some popup, the popups want to run correctly. Also, I want to create the previous button. how can I do it? please help me to fix the issue.

Here is the code I used.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
   var currentmodal = 1;
   $(".getAssignment").click(function() {
      var $divs = $(".modalDialog");
      var modal = $("*[data-modalorder="+(currentmodal++)+"]");
      if(!$("*[data-modalorder="+currentmodal+"]").length)
      {
          modal.find("input.getAssignment").prop("disabled",true);
      }
      if ($divs.length > 0 && modal) {
          window.location.href = "#" + $(modal).attr("id");
      }
   });
});

$(document).ready(function() {
       var currentmodal = 1;
       $(".getAssignment2").click(function() {
          var $divs = $(".modalDialog");
          var modal = $("*[data-modalorder="+(currentmodal--)+"]");
          if(!$("*[data-modalorder="+currentmodal+"]").length)
          {
              modal.find("input.getAssignment2").prop("disabled",true);
          }
          if ($divs.length > 0 && modal) {
              window.location.href = "#" + $(modal).attr("id");
          }
       });
    });

<input class="getAssignment" type="button" value="Open Modal">

<div id="openModal" class="modalDialog" data-modalorder=1>
    <div>
    <input class="getAssignment2" type="button" value="Previous">
    <input class="getAssignment" type="button" value="Next">
    <a href="#close" title="Close" class="close">X</a>
   <h2>Modal Box 1</h2>
        <p>This is a sample modal box that can be created using the powers of CSS3.</p>
        <p>You could do a lot of things here like have a pop-up ad that shows when your website loads, or create a login/register form for users.</p>
    </div>
</div>

<div id="openModal2" class="modalDialog" data-modalorder=2>
    <div>   
   <input class="getAssignment2" type="button" value="Previous">
   <input class="getAssignment" type="button" value="Next">
   <a href="#close" title="Close" class="close">X</a>
   <h2>Modal Box 2</h2>
        <p>This is a sample modal box that can be created using the powers of CSS3.</p>
        <p>You could do a lot of things here like have a pop-up ad that shows when your website loads, or create a login/register form for users.</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/Sanjeewani/q1tm8ck2/38/

Comment: you're executing the same code, whether you're clicking previous or next. 
you should check which button was clicked (e.g. by class or `data`-attribute), if next => `currentmodal++` if previous => `currentmodal--`

Comment: yes. You are right. But there is another issue. When disabling the next button, I tried to use the previous button. When the Previous button is disabled, The both are disabled. What is the issue?

Comment: Your line `modal.find("input.getAssignment").prop("disabled",true);` disables all inputs of the class `.getAssignment` - which are both the next and previous buttons.
You could give them each an individual class or id and disable/reenable them via that

Comment: yes. but a small issue I can see now. When disabling the next button, I tried to use the previous button. Again, when I tried to use the next button, It is not working properly. Have you any idea?

Comment: You'll need to reenable the `next` button upon clicking the `previous` button and vice versa. Otherwise, as soon as you've reached the last item, `next` will be disabled and remain disabled, even when you're clicking `previous`. (your buttons don't know which modal you're looking at) => that would be another possibility of handling this: On `$(.getAssignment).click()` check wich modal is currently visible and if it's the first, disable `previous` button (otherwise enable), if it's the last, disable `next` button (otherwise enable)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not exactly sure if this is what you want. But i tried rewriting your js a bit.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
 var data=[];
  currentModal = 0;
  
  $('.modalDialog').each(function(){
    data.push({
      id: $(this).attr('id'),
      order: $(this).data('modalorder')
    });
  })
    
 $('#openModalBtn').click(function(){
   currentModal = 0;
    window.location.href = "#" + data[currentModal].id;
    $('#'+data[currentModal].id).find('.getAssignment2').prop('disabled', true);
  })
  
  //prev
  $('.getAssignment2').click(function(){
   if (currentModal>0) {
     currentModal--;
      window.location.href = "#" + data[currentModal].id;
    } else {
      
     window.location.href = '#'
    }
  })
  
  //next
  $('.getAssignment').click(function(){
   if (currentModal<data.length - 1) {
     currentModal++;
      if (currentModal===data.length - 1) $('#'+data[currentModal].id).find('.getAssignment').prop('disabled', true);
      window.location.href = "#" + data[currentModal].id;
    } else {
     window.location.href = '#'
    }
  })
  
})
```

```css
.modalDialog {
    position: fixed;
    font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8);
    z-index: 99999;
    opacity:0;
    -webkit-transition: opacity 400ms ease-in;
    -moz-transition: opacity 400ms ease-in;
    transition: opacity 400ms ease-in;
    pointer-events: none;
}
.modalDialog:target {
    opacity:1;
    pointer-events: auto;
}
.modalDialog > div {
    width: 400px;
    position: relative;
    margin: 10% auto;
    padding: 5px 20px 13px 20px;
    border-radius: 10px;
    background: #fff;
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(#fff, #999);
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(#fff, #999);
    background: -o-linear-gradient(#fff, #999);
}
.close {
    background: #606061;
    color: #FFFFFF;
    line-height: 25px;
    position: absolute;
    right: -12px;
    text-align: center;
    top: -10px;
    width: 24px;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-weight: bold;
    -webkit-border-radius: 12px;
    -moz-border-radius: 12px;
    border-radius: 12px;
    -moz-box-shadow: 1px 1px 3px #000;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 1px 1px 3px #000;
    box-shadow: 1px 1px 3px #000;
}
.close:hover {
    background: #00d9ff;
}
.getAssignment{
  cursor:pointer;
}
```

```html
<meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>


<body>

<input type="button" id="openModalBtn" value="Open Modal">

<div id="openModal1" class="modalDialog" data-modalorder=1>
    <div>
    <input class="getAssignment2" type="button" value="Previous">
    <input class="getAssignment" type="button" value="Next">
    <a href="#close" title="Close" class="close">X</a>
   <h2>Modal Box 1</h2>
        <p>This is a sample modal box that can be created using the powers of CSS3.</p>
        <p>You could do a lot of things here like have a pop-up ad that shows when your website loads, or create a login/register form for users.</p>
    </div>
</div>

<div id="openModal2" class="modalDialog" data-modalorder=2>
    <div> 
   <input class="getAssignment2" type="button" value="Previous">
   <input class="getAssignment" type="button" value="Next">
   <a href="#close" title="Close" class="close">X</a>
   <h2>Modal Box 2</h2>
        <p>This is a sample modal box that can be created using the powers of CSS3.</p>
        <p>You could do a lot of things here like have a pop-up ad that shows when your website loads, or create a login/register form for users.</p>
    </div>
</div>

<div id="openModal3" class="modalDialog" data-modalorder=3>
    <div> 
      <input class="getAssignment2" type="button" value="Previous">
     <input class="getAssignment" type="button" value="Next">
   <a href="#close" title="Close" class="close">X</a>
   <h2>Modal Box 3</h2>
        <p>This is a sample modal box that can be created using the powers of CSS3.</p>
        <p>You could do a lot of things here like have a pop-up ad that shows when your website loads, or create a login/register form for users.</p>
    </div>
</div>

</body>
```

Comment: yes, This is the code actually I need. Can I automatically disable the button after loading all pop-ups? Have you any Idea?

Comment: I just edited the code to disable the "prev" button on the first popup and the "next" button on the last popup. Is that what you are asking for?